# Is there a way to pass props to a contained component in react?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props, children

If I have a component defined like so:

```
export default class LinkContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.props.baselink}>
          <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
        </a>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is there a way to pass `this.props.baselink` to all of the components in `this.props.children`?

Comment: One option is to use context: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement). Map over your children and clone each one, passing a second argument to the cloneElement, which will act as props. [isValidElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#isvalidelement) is used in this example in case you have children that can't be cloned, such as a text node.

```
export default class LinkContainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <a href={this.props.baselink}>
          <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
        </a>
        {Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
          if (!isValidElement(child)) return child;
          return cloneElement(child, { baselink: this.props.baselink });
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here it is in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-dream-9650n